# Chess Massacre Variants-Play Find The Fastest Way?

Tags: mathematics, chess, checkerboard, game-theory, speedsolving

I have thought up several variations of *massacre chess*.

> **Massacre chess** is a game where almost every single move is a capture. 
>   The idea here is that only the chosen type of piece can capture. It can only be captured itself, by the kings of course, once all other possible captures have been done.

This idea for this has the following variations: Kings, Knights, Queens, Rooks, Bishops, Black Bishops, White Bishops, No-Promotion Pawns, and Yes-Promotion Pawns.

This a question to be answered by those of you who wish to do this for fun.

---

I shall now list my research, and the challenge is for you to beat my games for each variation by making a faster version.

You may choose to do one, two, or all of the. It is up to you. Good luck!

> **Rules**
>
> 1. Only the chosen type of piece may capture.
> 2. The board must be cleared down to two kings.
> 3. The kings may only take the chosen piece once every other capture possible with that piece has been done.
> 4. It can only be done through legal moves - think FIDE.
> 5. Have fun!

The variants (external links to https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/ )

- [Knights](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_Nf6_Ng5_Ng4_Nxf7_Nxf2_Nxh8_Nxh1_g3_g6_Nxg6_Nxg3_Nxf8_Nxf1_Nxh7_Nxh2_Nc3_Nc6_Nb5_Nb4_Nxc7_Kf7_Nxa8_Nxc2_Kf2_Nxa1_b3_b6_Nxb6_Nxb3_Nxc8_Nxc1_Nxa7_Nxa2_Qc1_Nxc1_d4_Qc8_Nxc8_Nxe2_Nxe7_d5_Nxd5_Nxd4_Ne3_Ne6_Ng4_Ng5_Nxh2_Nxh7_Ng4_Ng5_Ne5_Kf6_Nf3_Nxf3_Kxf3)
- [Kings](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e3_d6_Ke2_Kd7_Kf3_Kc6_Bb5*_Kxb5_b4_Bg4*_Kxg4_g5_Nc3*_Kxb4_Ba3*_Kxa3_Nb1*_Kb2_Qc1*_Kxc1_Kxg5_Nf6_h3_Bh6*_Kxh6_Ng8*_Kg7_Qf8*_Kxf8_Kb2_Kg7_Kxa1_Kxh8_Kxa2_Kxh7_Kxb1_Kxg8_Kxc2_Kxf7_Kxd2_Kxe7_Nd7_Ne2_Kxe2_Kxd7_Kxf2_Kxc7_Kxe3_Kxd6_Kf2_Kc7_Kxg2_Kxb7_Kxh1_Kxa8_Kh2_Kxa7_Kxh3)
- [Queens](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_e5_Qg4_Qh4_Qxg7_Qxh2_Qxh7_Qxh1_Qxh8_Qxg1_Qxg8_Qxg2_Qg7_Qxe4_Be2_Qxc2_Qxe5_Be7_Qxc7_Kf8_Kf1_Kg7_Kg2_Qxb2_Qxb7_Qxa2_Qxa7_Qxa1_Qxa8_Qxb1_Qxb8_Qxc1_Qxc8_Qxd2_Qxd7_Qxe2_Qxe7_Qxf2_Kh1_Kg6_Qxf7_Kg5_Qxf2_Kg4_Qg3_Kxg3)
- [Rooks](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=a4_a5_Ra3_Ra6_Rh3_Rb6_Rxh7_Rxb2_Rxg7_Rxh2_Rxg8_Rxg2_Rh7_d6_Rxf8_Kd7_Rhxf7_Rxb1_Rxd8_Kc6_Rxe7_Rxc1_Rxc8_Rxg1_Rxb8_Rxc2_Rxb7_Rxd2_f3_Rxd1_Kf2_Rgxf1_Kg2_Rxf3_Rexc7_Kd5_Rb5_Ke6_Rxa5_Rd4_Rc6_Rxa4_Rxa4_Re3_Rxd6_Kf5_Ra2_Rxe2_Rxe2_Kf4_Re4_Kxe4_Rd5_Kxd5)
- [Bishops](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_d5_e4_e5_Bf4_Bf5_Bc4_Bc5_Bxd5_Bxd4_Bxe5_Bxe4_Bxc7_Bxc2_Bxf7_Kf8_Bxb8_Bxf2_Kf1_Bxb1_Bxa7_Bxa2_b3_b6_Bxb6_Bxb3_Ra2_Ra7_Bxa7_Bxa2_Bxg8_Bxg1_Bxh7_Bxh2_g3_g6_Bxg6_Bxg3_Rh2_Rh7_Bxh7_Bxh2_Qd5_Qb6_Bxb6_Bxd5_Bg1_Bg8_Bxg8_Bxg1_Kxg1_Kxg8)
- [Only Black Bishops](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_e5_Bf4_Bc5_Bxe5_Bxd4_a3_h6_c3_f6_Nd2_Ne7_Rc1_Rf8_e3_d6_g3_b6_h4_a5_Rh2_Ra7_Ke2_Bxc3_Qe1_Bxb2_Bxf6_Bxa3_Bxg7_Bxc1_Bxh6_Bxd2_Bxf8_Bxe1_Bxe7_Bxf2_Bxd8_Bxe3_Bxc7_Bxg1_Bxd6_Bxh2_Bxb8_Bxg3_Bxa7_Bxh4_Bxb6_Bh3_Bxa5_Bxf1*_Kxf1_Bd8_Bxd8_Kxd8)
- [Only White Bishops](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_d5_Bc4_Bf5_Bxd5_Bxe4_f3_c6_h3_a6_d3_e6_b3_g6_Ne2_Nd7_a4_h5_Ra2_Rh7_Bxe6_Ke7_Bxf7_Qe8_Bxg8_Bxd3_Bxh7_Bxc2_Bxg6_Bxb1_Bxh5_Bxa2_Bxe8_Bxb3_Bxd7_Bxa4_Bxc6_Bxd1_Bxb7_Bxe2_Bxa8_Bxf3_Bb7_Bxg2_Bxa6_Bxh1_Bc8_Bg2_Bh6_Bxh3_Bxh3_Bxh6_Be6_Bd2_Kxd2_Kxe6)
- [No-Promotion Pawns](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_c5_f4_e5_f5_d5_Bf4_Be6_fxe6_exf4_e4_f5_e5_c4_Bd3_Bc5_dxc5_cxd3_c4_a5_b4_a4_Qb3_axb3_a4_b5_Kd1_Ra5_bxa5_Nf6_exf6_Qe7_fxe7_g5_h4_g4_Nf3_gxf3_g4_d4_Nc3_dxc3_Ra2_bxa2_Rg1_Rg8_Rg3_Rg5_hxg5_fxg3_Kc1_Nd7_exd7_Kf7_cxb5_c2_g6_hxg6_Kb2_fxg4_Kxa2_Kxe7_Kb2_Kxd7_Kc3_Ke6_Kxd3_Kd5_Kxc2_Kxc5_Kd3_Kb4_Ke3_Kxa5_Kf4_g5_Kxg5_Kxa4_Kxg4_Kxb5_Kxg3_Kc4_Kxf3)
- [Yes-Promotion Pawns](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nc3_Nc6_Na4_Na5_Nb6_Nb3_cxb3_cxb6_Nf3_Nf6_Nh4_Nh5_Ng6_Ng3_fxg3_fxg6_d4_d5_e4_e5_Bf4_Bf5_Bc4_Bc5_dxc5_dxc4_exf5_exf4_h4_h5_a4_a5_Rh2_Rh7_Ra2_Ra7_fxg6_cxb3_cxb6_fxg3_bxa7_gxh2_gxh7_bxa2_Qg4_Qb6_Kd2_Qb5_axb5_hxg4_a8ZQ_Kf7_Qxa5_h1ZQ_Qxa2_Kf8_Qa7_Qxg2_Ke3_Qxb2_Qxb7_Qxb5_Qxg7_Ke8_Qxg4_Qh5_Qd7_Kxd7_Kf4_Qxh7_Kg4_Qxh4_Kxh4) 
  Since if a promoted pawn counts as a piece or not is debatable, this
  is a variation to cover that. There is a special rule for this
  one-you may only promote after all possible piece and pawn captures
  have been done in whatever position/s arise in your game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Does this beat your rooks file? (25 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=h4_h5_Rh3_Rh6_Ra3_Rb6_Rxa7_Rxb2_Rxb7_Rxb1_Rxb8_Rxc1_Rxc8_Rxc2_Rxc7_Rcxa2_Rxa2_Rxa2_Rxd7_Rxd2_g4_g5_f4_f5_Kf2_Kf7_Rxd8_Rxd1_Ke3_Ke6_Rxf8_Rxf1_Rxg8_Rxg1_Rxg5_Rxg4_Rxh5_Rxh4_Kd3_Kd6_e4_e5_Rxf5_Rxf4_Rxe5_Rxe4_Rxe4_Kd5_Re5*_Kxe5)

[And the Queens (21.5 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_d5_Qd3_Qd6_Qxh7_Qxh2_Qxh8_Qxh1_Qxg7_Qxg2_Qxg8_Qxg1_f3_f6_Qxd5_Qxd4_Qxb7_Qxb2_Qxa7_Qxa2_Qxa8_Qxa1_Qxb8_Qxb1_Qxc7_Qxc2_Kf2_Qxc1_Qxc8*_Kf7_Kg3_Kg6_Qxf8_Qxf1_Qxe7_Qxe2_Kh4_Qxf3_Qxf6*_Qxf6*_Kh3_Qh4*_Kxh4)

Again [Queens, same score](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_e5_Qh5_Qh4_Qxh7_Qxh2_Qxg8_Qxg1_Qxg7_Qxg2_Qxe5*_Be7_Be2_Qxe4_O-O_O-O_Qxe7_Qxe2_Qxf7*_Kh8_Qxd7_Qxf2*_Kh1_Qxd2_Qxc8_Qxc1_Qxc7_Qxc2_Qxb8_Qxb1_Qxb7_Qxa1_Qxa7_Qxb2_Qxa8_Qxa2_Rf7_Qxf7_Qxf8*_Qxf8_Kg2_Qf2*_Kxf2), with an interesting idea.

[The Bishops (23 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_e5_d4_d5_Bc4_Bc5_Bxd5_Bxd4_Bxb7_Bxb2_Bxa8_Bxa1_Bf4_Bf5_Bxe5_Bxe4_Bxc7_Bxc2_Bxb8_Bxb1_Bxa7_Bxa2_Bd4_Bd5_Bxg7_Bxg2_Bxh8_Bxh1_Bxh1_Bxh8_Qd4_Qd5_Bxd5_Bxd4_Ke2_Ke7_Be4_Be5_Bxh7_Bxh2_Bxg8_Bxg1_Bxf7_Bxf2_Kxf2_Kxf7)

[NP pawns (35 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_c5_f4_e5_f5_d5_Bf4_Be6_fxe6_exf4_e4_f5_e5_c4_Bd3_Bc5_dxc5_cxd3_c4_a5_b4_a4_Qb3_axb3_a4_b5_Kd1_Ra5_bxa5_Nf6_exf6_Qe7_fxe7_g5_h4_g4_Nf3_gxf3_g4_d4_Nc3_dxc3_Ra2_bxa2_Rg1_Rg8_Rg3_Rg5_hxg5_fxg3_Kc1_Nd7_exd7_Kf7_cxb5_c2_g6_hxg6_Kb2_fxg4_Kxa2_Kxe7_Kb2_Kxd7_Kc3_Ke6_Kxd3_Kd5_Kxc2_Kxc5_Kd3_Kb4_Ke3_Kxa5_Kf4_g5_Kxg5_Kxa4_Kxg4_Kxb5_Kxg3_Kc4_Kxf3)

[YP pawns (33.5 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=h4_g5_hxg5_Nh6_gxh6_Bg7_hxg7_h5_g4_hxg4_Rh3_gxh3_Bg2_hxg2_f4_e5_fxe5_f6_exf6_Qe7_fxe7_d5_e4_dxe4_d3_exd3_Qe2_dxe2_a4_b5_axb5_a5_bxa6_Bb7_axb7_Ra3_bxa3_Na6_Bf4_Nb4_axb4_Rh5_Bd6_cxd6_Nf3_Rc5_bxc5_dxc5_Nd4_cxd4_Nc3_dxc3_Rb1_Kf7_Rb2_cxb2_g8ZQ*_Kxe7_Kxe2_b1ZQ_Qxg2_Qxb7_Kd2_Qxg2*_Kd3_Qxc2*_Kxc2)

[Dark square Bishops (26.5 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=d4_e5_a3_h6_Bxh6_Bxa3_Bxg7_Bxb2_Bxh8_Bxa1_Qd2_Nf6_Nc3_Bxc3_Bxf6_Bxd4_Kd1_Bxf2_Bxe5_Bxg1_Bxc7_b6_g3_Bxh2_Bxb8_Bxg3_Rh2_Bxh2_e3_d6_Bxd6_Rb8_Bxb8_Bf4_Bxa7_Bxe3_Bxb6_f6_Bxd8_Bxd2_c3_Bxc3_Bxf6_Bxf6_Bc4_Bf5_Bf7*_Kxf7_Kd2_Bd3_Kxd3_Bd4_Kxd4)  (with constraint added that Light square Bishops can only be captured by a King)

[Light square Bishops (25.5 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e4_d5_h3_a6_Bxa6_Bxh3_Bxb7_Bxg2_Bxa8_Bxh1_Nf3_e6_Bxd5_Bxf3_Bxe6_Ke7_d3_Bxe4_Bxf7_Bxd3_Bxg8_Bxc2_Bxh7_g6_Bxg6_Bxb1_b3_Bxa2_f3_Bxb3_Be8_c6_Bxc6_Qd7_Bxd7_Bxd1_Ra8_Bxf3_Kf2_Rh3_Bh6_Bxa8_Bxh3_Nd7_Bxd7_Kxd7_Bxf8_Bf3_Be7_Kxe7_Kxf3) (without the additional constraint above)

[Kings (28 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=e3_e6_Ke2_Ke7_Kf3_Kd6_Kf4_Qg5*_Kxg5_Kd5_Bc4*_Kxc4_c3_g6_a3_Nf6_Qb3*_Kxb3_Kxf6_Bg7*_Kxg7_Kc2_Kxh8_Kxc1_Kxh7_f6_Kxg6_Kxb2_Kxf6_Kxa1_Ke7_Kxb1_Kd8_Ka2_Kxc8_Kxa3_Kxb7_Kb3_d3_Kxc3_Kxa8_Kxd3_Ne2_Kxe2_Kxa7_Kxf2_Kxb8_Kxe3_Kxc7_Kf2_Kxd7_Kxg2_Kxe6_Kxh1_Kf6_Kxh2)

[Knights (wait for it) (20 moves)](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_Nf6_Ng5_Ng4_Nxh7_Nxh2_Nxf8_Nxf1_Nxd7_Nxd2_Nxb8_Nxb1_c3_c6_Nxc6_Nxc3_Nxa7_Nxa2_Nxc8_Nxc1_Nxe7_Nxe2_g3_g6_Nxg6_Nxg3_Nxh8_Nxh1_Nxf7_Nxf2_Nxd8_Nxd1_Nxb7_Nxb2_Rd1_Rd8_Nxd8_Nxd1_Kxd1_Kxd8) Well, I guess this variation breaks the king-capture rule again, so [23 moves](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_Nf6_Ng5_Ng4_Nxh7_Nxh2_Nxf8_Nxf1_Nxd7_Nxd2_Nxb8_Nxb1_c3_c6_Nxc6_Nxc3_Nxa7_Nxa2_Nxc8_Nxc1_Nxe7_Nxe2_g3_g6_Nxg6_Nxg3_Nxh8_Nxh1_Nxf7_Nxf2_Nxd8_Nxd1_Nxb7_Nxb2_Rd1_Rd8_Nxd8_Nxd1_Ne6_Nc3_Nd8_Nd5_Nc6_Ne7_Nxe7_Kxe7) is all I can do.