# Chess Bloodshed

Tags: chess, optimization, checkerboard

This puzzle is the idea of Dmitry Kamenetsky in a comment of my puzzle [Devouring Nobility](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104174/51928).

---

Find, with the minimum number of moves, a legal game where all pieces are captured except the two kings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution in 16.5 moves exists, created by Italian composer G. Ponzetto in 2000. I found it being posted by user @AussieRookie in this [chess.com thread](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/fastest-way-to-have-only-kings-left-on-the-board):

> 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Bd3 Qxa2 4. Bxh7 Qxb1 5. Bxg8 Qxc2 6. Bxf7+ Kxf7 7. Rxa7 Qxc1 8. Rxb7 Rxh2 9. Rxb8 Rxg2 10. Qxc1 Rxg1+ 11. Rxg1 Rxb8 12. Qxc7 Rxb2 13. Qxc8 Rxd2 14. Qxf8+ Kxf8 15. Rxg7 Rxf2 16. Rxe7 Kxe7 17. Kxf2
>
>  [PGN viewer / replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/904/7297)

Comment: Since there are 15 pieces and we cannot take any piece on the first move, the minimum is 16 moves.

Comment: This only plays 1.5 moves where a piece isn't captured. I'd be amazed if there was a better solution.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky You can take two pieces in a move with en passant, but i wonder if it might take too much setup to be used

Comment: How can you take two pieces in one move with en passant? If you are taking a piece with a diagonal move then the pawn couldn't have advanced two spaces.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in

> [20 moves](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?m=Nf3_Nf6_Ng5_Ng4_Nxh7_Nxh2_Nxf8_Nxf1_Nxd7_Nxd2_Nxb8_Nxb1_c3_c6_Nxc6_Nxc3_Nxa7_Nxa2_Nxc8_Nxc1_Nxe7_Nxe2_g3_g6_Nxg6_Nxg3_Nxh8_Nxh1_Nxf7_Nxf2_Nxd8_Nxd1_Nxb7_Nxb2_Rd1_Rd8_Nxd8_Nxd1_Kxd1_Kxd8) with knights. From [Chess Massacre Variants-Play Find The Fastest Way?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80286/chess-massacre-variants-play-find-the-fastest-way). But I am pretty sure faster solutions are possible.